# How to retrieve files from Samsung Galaxy S4 stuck at samsung logo after dropping it?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I dropped my Galaxy S4 GT-19500 and after i picked it up it was still open but when i tried to phone a friend it just turned off and kept turning on and off, it reaches the Samsung logo then immediately turn off and when i plug it to the pc or the charger it shows the big battery bar but empty with the circle and also flashing on and off like the Samsung logo, the problem is when i try to turn it off it doesn't turn off and when i take the battery and put it again it just go on alone, so i can't enter safe mode or recovery mode and can't connect it to the PC and Dr. Fone, i think it doesn't charge when i leave it too.

So what i need is to get the photos from my phone, i don't care what to do I will do it! Please help me I really need those photos i don't care about the phone XD.

If it's not possible to get the photos with the known ways, Is it possible to take the default SD card of the phone and take the photos from it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, odds are good you can salvage your photos.

Provided you did *not* encrypt your sd card, pull the sd card and take a look at it with a desktop/laptop (you won't be able to pull anything useable off of it this way if you did indeed encrypt it).  The images will be on there *if* you set up your camera app to save them there.  Otherwise...

Hardware repair on the phone will be required to get the connectors all back and sorted out (it sounds like you managed to short or unplug some bits, and perhaps damaged connectors on the motherboard). If you are feeling mechanical we can walk through looking at it; if not, we can suggest other repair options.

Comment: I really don't feel mechanical xD, I'd like your other repair options because I'm very bad when it comes to the hardware things. Thanks

Comment: @GasserTarek it takes a brave soul to admit that ;-)  I'm not sure that we can actively recommend vendors here, so I'll go with a generic "start with where you bought it" and ask them for prices on the repair (yes, it will be pricey). You can also google for mail-in repair services, but do your homework on them - you don't want a place that will lose the photos by careless repair.